# verify that no call was done to a method on a mocked item using Moq

Tags: mocking, moq

I sometimes need to test that a method **was not called** at all.  In that case, I usually specify all parameters as `It.IsAny<>`, so that any call will be logged.

Is it possible such that rather I have to do:

```
    GetMockFor<IMediaItemImageManipulationService>()
                    .Verify(
                        x => x.ResizeImagesForMediaItem(
                            It.IsAny<IMediaItem>(),
                            It.IsAny<ImageSizeInfoData>(),
                            It.IsAny<Stream>()
                            ),
                        Times.Never());
```

I could do say something like below?

```
    GetMockFor<IMediaItemImageManipulationService>()
                    .Verify(
                        x => x.ResizeImagesForMediaItem,
                        Times.Never());
```

Comment: I don't think any simplification from the `It.IsAny()` is possible, since there may be multiple overloads of `ResizeImagesForMediaItem` which would need to be differentiated in the `Verify`. But agree this is cumbersome for methods with large signatures.

Comment: @StuartLC I didn't think about multiple signatures honestly - I can understand how that can be a problem.  Thanks for pointing it out.  In this case and most of my cases, they never had multiple overloads so it never came to light.